# Получение определённого значения из JSON

Tags: java, json

Есть такой JSON в ответе от сервера:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "nickname": "YalikesiFulei",
            "account_id": 36791942
        }
    ]
}
```

Как мне распарсить и достать значение `account_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](http://json.org/json-ru.html) перечислены все библиотеки для работы с JSON для всех языков. Обычно все сводится к тому, чтобы создать классы, идентичные получаемым данным, а библиотека создаст для вас объекты этих классов из полученного JSON.

А [здесь](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) вы сможете вставив JSON код и получить Java-класс для работы с ним. Также такие генераторы есть для других языков.

Comment: И какую же лучше выбрать?

Comment: Ну это уже другой вопрос=). К сожалению посоветовать ничего не могу т.к. пишу на C#.

Comment: Например [этот](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html) выглядит довольно просто и обучалка есть.

Comment: *И какую же лучше выбрать?* - Наиболее применяемый json маппер на данный момент - это Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, насколько гибкое решение вы хотите. У вас может измениться формат получаемого JSON?
Можно либо захардкодить путь (просто, быстро, если у вас мало данных используется), либо выкладывать дерево на плоскость и искать нужное поле (гибко, медленее, еще кучу полей хотите доставать). Как компромисс - единожды выкладывать, кэшировать, а по запросу от сервера "у нас обновилась структура JSON"  - обновлять.

Comment: Использую библиотеку Argo, при парсинге выдает ошибки `argo.jdom.JsonNodeDoesNotMatchPathElementsException: Failed to find an element at index [1] at ["data".1] while resolving ["data".1] in [{"status":"ok","meta":{"count":1},"data":[{"nickname":"YalikesiFulei","account_id":36791942}]}].` Код запроса `String json = response.toString();
  System.out.println(json);
  String id = new JdomParser().parse(json)
  .getStringValue("data", 1); `

Comment: Что делать в этом случае?

Comment: @Yalikesifulei data[0] может?.. У вас в приведенных данных только нулевой элемент, 1го нет, вот он и не может найти наверное.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei нумерация с нуля начинается в смысле

Comment: про это знаю. Но ошибка та же самая.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791577/parsing-json-with-argo